# Check bit or use boolean?

Tags: c++, optimization

I get a point in the 2-D plane (x,y) as input. Now I have to check which quadrant it is in, do some Reflections about X-axis and Y-axis and check again which quadrant it is in repeatedly for a large number of times.

I have two approaches but not sure which is better

1. I can store initially the x,y as boolean and then do boolean operations when Reflecting and hence this will be easy. To tell which quadrant the point is in just check the value is true or false.
2. Or I can do the normal approach with int and then check the first bit to find which quadrant the point is in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither, just compare your coordinates to `0`.

If you store them as boolean, besides losing information, you'll probably get some overhead because of the conversion.

If you check the first bit, it will be less readable.

The compiler will optimize these calls on its own, doubt you'll gain anything from a different approach.

Comment: I thought comparing with 0 will take more time than comparing single bit or checking the value of bool

Comment: no, it depends on the compiler if it will check only  the first bit to compare with 0

Comment: @nischayn22 the compiler is very good at doing this sort of micro-optimizations. Also, note that checking a bool can theoretically be slower than checking an int, because it needs to be promoted to word-size. Aim for readability when you write the code, and only after profiling do these sort of changes.

Comment: Oh checking bool can be slower, then we should always store value in int and check that bit? also could you explain how should I reflect the coordinates (for bool all I did was y=!y)?

Comment: For int it would be `y = -y;`

Comment: @nischayn22 again, in practice, it's probably the same.

Comment: thanks, I was complicating things underestimating the compiler